# Pair with each value from first list with second list

Tags: python

I need to write loop for each value of the first list should to paired with each value of second list

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_2 = [100,101,102]

for x in list_1:
    for y in list_2:
        pair_list =
```

expected output is [[1,100],[1,1001],[1,102],[2,100]....

Comment: you can use built-in `zip` function but lists shuld have same length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_2 = [100,101,102]

print([[y, x] for y in list_1 for x in list_2])
```

Or

```
pair_list = []
for x in list_1:
    for y in list_2:
        pair_list.append([x,y])
print(pair_list)
```

Output

```
[[1, 100], [1, 101], [1, 102], [2, 100], [2, 101], [2, 102], [3, 100], [3, 101], [3, 102], [4, 100], [4, 101], [4, 102], [5, 100], [5, 101], [5, 102]]
```

This nested list comprehension will return a list of each combination between values in list_1 and list_2

Comment: Hello Leo, I need to with for loop without using comprehensions or any imports

Comment: You can use the Or part that will do the same with nested loops. that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes... it worked thank you.. I was using this code pair_list.append(x,y) but again append takes only one parameter but the code you gave helped me :)

Comment: You welcome, it will be appreciated if you can mark the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product`

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(list_1, list_2))
[(1, 100), (1, 101), (1, 102), (2, 100), (2, 101), (2, 102), (3, 100), (3, 101), (3, 102), (4, 100), (4, 101), (4, 102), (5, 100), (5, 101), (5, 102)]
```

Or if you want a list of lists, you can do something similar with a list comprehension

```
>>> [list(i) for i in product(list_1, list_2)]
[[1, 100], [1, 101], [1, 102], [2, 100], [2, 101], [2, 102], [3, 100], [3, 101], [3, 102], [4, 100], [4, 101], [4, 102], [5, 100], [5, 101], [5, 102]]
```

Comment: Hello Cory, I need to with for loop without using comprehensions or any imports

Comment: @Chandrakanth Is this for a homework assignment? You should mention any such restrictions in your question.